# Why are my react components not rendering with createBrowserRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, create-react-app

I am using `createBrowserRouter` to manage routes, but unable to render any data from my components, why? I am navigating to the correct URL path it seems, but nothing displays from the components. In this example, no content from the about page.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Skills from './Skills'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <Home />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'about',
        element: <About />
      },
      {
        path: 'skills',
        element: <Skills />
      }
    ],
  
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does the `Home` component render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content?

Comment: Or do you want `Home`, `About`, and `Skills` to each render on their own independent pages?

Comment: yes - so url path changes but no content. when user clicks the link or links, respective page content should be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Home` component is rendered as a layout route, so it *must* render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render out their `element` content.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
  </>
);
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <Home />,
    children: [
      { path: 'about', element: <About /> },
      { path: 'skills', element: <Skills /> }
    ],
  },
]);
```

If you would like to render `Home`, `About`, and `Skills` each on their own pages, independent from each other and the `Navbar` then create a navbar layout route component that is separate from the `Home` component UI.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

```
const Home = () => (
  <>
    ...
  </>
);
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: 'about', element: <About /> },
      { path: 'skills', element: <Skills /> }
    ],
  },
]);
```

For more details see:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Index Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)